# URL format with GET parameters?

Tags: php, http

Is there a specification somewhere listing the correct way to pass GET variables to a URL?

Normally I do it like this (first variable indicated by ?, second and subsequent indicated by &:

```
http://www.mysite.com/mypage.html?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3
```

Are those ? and & specifically needed, and in those order? Could I eliminate the '?' and pass all variables only with the '&' ?

Comment: Read the RFC's please.  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt makes it quite clear.  If you have further questions, please include a reference to the part of the defined syntax for URI's that confuses you.

Comment: Depends on the webserver setup. You could very well configure a RewriteRule to accept `&` in place of the `?` for delimiting the query string. And PHP for example accepts `;` instead of `&` with the default `arg_separator.input` setting. It just won't work generically with all servers and doesn't match established URL schemes.

Comment: S.Lott: RFC 2396 has been obsoleted a *long* time ago by RFC 3986. Furthermore it defines the separator between path and query ("?"), but not the contents of the query string.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, how you are doing it is correct.

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.2

Comment: Ok, thanks. I knew that what I am currently doing is correct, but I was more wondering if there's alternative ways.

Comment: Not without parting from the standards in  place.