# What do a question mark (?) and an ampersand (&) mean in a URL?

Tags: url

I saw a link like this:

`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=YOUR_SITE_KEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

I know that it's setting the secret variable to YOUR_SITE_KEY and response to `response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but, I'm not sure what those symbols means that is, the `?` and `&` in the query string.

Comment: That's standard format for a URL [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), providing a list of `key=value` pairs to a web script. The `?` introduces the list of arguments, and the `&` separates each key/value pair.

Comment: [link anatomy seems relevant](http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/3070589)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL format with GET parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998425/url-format-with-get-parameters)

Comment: oops, I did not look better than that :(

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There isn't really anything there that is particular to PHP.

The `?` indicates the start of the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Within the query string you have a set of `key=value` pairs, each separated by an `&`.

PHP will populate `$_GET` with this data. It is part of the URL standard and any server side language will have a parser that provides similar functionality.

This is also the default data format browsers generate when submitting a form.

Comment: I have always wondered why the ampersand instead of using the question mark again. That would make more characters URL-safe. What would be the issue with doing that?

Comment: @PostSelf — 3 decades of backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 7):

When used as part of a URL, ? and & represent key value pairs that make up the Query String, which is a set of information sent to the server.

The query string starts after the end of the page being requested with a ? and then a key value pair like:

```
?variable1=value1
```

Any additional key/value pairs need to be prefaced with & like:

```
?variable1=value1&variable2=value2&variable3=value3
```

Answer (score 4):

In HTTP request, there are either GET or POST request types and the basic difference in these requests is, how parameters/values are send in the HTTP request. However in GET request, parameters are attached to URL.

For e.g. 
http://xlntstudios.com/index.php is the url and after url symbol ? tells, anything after the ? has parameters passed to URL in key/value pairs. Where as each key=value pair is separated by & symbol.

[http://xlntstudios.com/index.php?name=Atul&age=31&city=Portland](http://xlntstudios.com/index.php)

so here key/value pairs are

```
name=Atul
age=31
city=Portland
```

each one separated by & symbol.