# URL in parameter redirects to 403?

Tags: php, url

I'm developing a PHP site which I take parameters and I process its data according by the given parameters, however I'm having a bit of a problem with a specific URL query, looking at this [What do a question mark (?) and an ampersand (&) mean in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252310/what-do-a-question-mark-and-an-ampersand-mean-in-a-url) I understood a bit more how parameters works, but I still need to know what's causing the issue.

the url in question is: `http://mydomain.xyz/load.php?char=HellHound&Platform=Win32NT&id=ab38df8h3ff&host=http://mydomain.xyz/`

the `host` parameter, is not getting parsed by PHP, and is instead getting thrown as a (Access Denied) 403 error, I have spoken to my web host and they claim it's not an issue with the actual server or the file system, but with the development itself, so here I am.

How can I process this parameter so it doesn't defaults to 403 every single time?

---

This is the code in `load.php` (right now it's just a place holder)

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET['host']);
//var_dump($_GET['char']);
//var_dump($_GET['Platform']);
//var_dump($_GET['id']);
//echo "success";
?>
```

---

Whenever I try to use `var_dump()` or anything similar it won't just process the content it will automatically redirect to 403

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, **specific problems, and code to reproduce it**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Because of some characters (like '/') you have to use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Show us your code.  Also, while not strictly required in this specific instance, I'd URL-encode those characters in the URL.  A poorly configured server may try to make meaning out of those slashes.

Comment: Updated post with some code