# How to make PHP get special characters like "&" from the URL link

Tags: php

Need some help here....

```
<a href='Delete.php?id=$itemid'>Delete</a>
$itemid=$_GET["id"];
echo $itemid;
```

The code is able to grab the id from the previous link to the next page but once it encounter special id like "m&b". It is not able to read the "&" character. What can I do? I echo the itemid to check and php only get the character "m" and not the whole.

Comment: encode special chars in your <a href="..."> URLs

Comment: Do you have any sample on how to do that?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252356/7406948 | You must use the encoded & (%26) https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this will work

```
<a href='Delete.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($itemid); ?>'>Delete</a>
```

Then you can use **urldecode()** to decode.

```
$itemid=urldecode($_GET["id"]);
echo $itemid;
```

[urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function encodes the url string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.