# $_GET Double "WHERE" Function ?name=Hannes

Tags: php

I have a question about the $_GET function. This is my code:

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect  ('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'producten'); 
$query =            "SELECT DISTINCT Groep, Artikelnummer, Artikelnaam, Merk, Groep, Prijs
                    FROM producten
                    WHERE Groep = '" .$_GET['groep'] . "'  
                    ";
    /*echo $query;*/
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
?>
<table>
<?php
    echo '<table style="width:100%">
            <tr style="color:yellow; background-color:black;">
                <th>' . $_GET['groep'] . '</th>
            </tr>';
    foreach ($result AS $rij)
{

     echo '<tr style="background:blue"><td>' . $rij['Artikelnummer'] . ' </td>' . 
     '<td>' . $rij['Artikelnaam']   . ' </td>' .
     '<td>' . $rij['Merk']  . ' </td>' .
     '<td>' . $rij['Groep']     . ' </td>' .
     '<td>' . $rij['Prijs']         . ' </td></tr>';



}
?>
```

If I go to the browser with the URL: `http://localhost/view.php?groep=cases`
I see all the "cases" in the database but I only want to see the cases from the mark('Merk') Apple.

Of course I needed to change the URL for that but what do I have to change in the code? Something like: `WHERE Groep = '" .$_GET['groep'] . "' AND Merk = '" .$_GET['merk'] . "'`

And the URL: `http://localhost/view.php?groep=cases?merk=apple`?

Comment: Since your code is wide open to SQL injection, you can just put the SQL code you want to execute right in the query string.  (Note: So can anybody else, including SQL code to delete all of your data or otherwise compromise your server.)  If you're asking how to use SQL with PHP, you should really start with some tutorials on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't do it that way. Assign your get variables to a variable.

If you're doing it via get anything in the url after mypage.php?x=__&y=

Use & to separate variables, your get variable name = value to be passed

```
$x = $_GET['x']
$y = $_GET['y']
```

Then use a prepared statement: Lets say x is groep

s, s for string, i for integers are the number of variables within the query, ? is the placeholders for where you'd put variables within the WHERE clause.

2 bind variables it'd be bind->param("ss",$var,$var2)

3 bind variables 1 integer bind_param("ssi",$var,$var2,$int)

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Groep, Artikelnummer, Artikelnaam, Merk, Groep, Prijs
                    FROM producten
                    WHERE Groep =?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$x);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($groep,artikelnummer,......,$prijs);   // Variables are like $row['groep'] assignments.

// Loop through all the rows, if you don't loop it'll only pull the first record with a $stmt->fetch();

while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo $groep;
    echo $artiteknummer;
    ...
    ...
    echo $prijs
} 
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Don't need to escape with prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Just... `http://localhost/view.php?groep=cases&merk=apple`

Use **&** for variables after usage the first one **?**

Answer (score 0):

[URL format with GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998425/url-format-with-get-parameters)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Also, you should NEVER use MySQL code like that, use prepared statements.