# Cross domain data transfer

Tags: php, asp.net, cross-domain

Is it possible to send parameters through a link from a .net project to a PHP project having different domains ?? If yes then what could be the possible ways.
I am trying to send data over a link from .net project to php project for auto login.

Comment: Send data using query string or you can use tokens to check login.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have tried using json and it didnt work but seeking for some other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible.
If you want to do that through a link you can do that using GET parameters.

Here are some infos about how it is intended to be done: [URL format with GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998425/9606459)

Comment: Thanks, feel free to ask further question if you need help.

Answer (score 2):

you can send the data through query string and try to use token also for validation. if you share some example which type of data you want to share that would be great to explore your requirement.

you can also share xml data if long data is required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to send username and registration_id through the link which will be present in my .net project to php project.